# Sqldependency - Records added while processing

Tags: c#, sql, sqldependency

I have a question on sql dependency. Lets assume my application receives notification when the underlying query data changes and I am planning to select the data from table, process it and resubscribe/start the dependency again. If the processing takes 1-2 minutes and in the mean time there may be some data added during this processing time. Not sure how that data will get notified or do I have to wait for the next change to occur which can be few minutes to hrs?

Below is my sample code let me know if I am missing something

Code:

```
    private void LoadNotifications()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID FROM dbo.NOTIFICATIONS", m_sqlConn))
        {
            command.Notification = null;

            SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
            dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);

            if (m_sqlConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                m_sqlConn.Open();
            }



            //using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            //{
            //    if (reader.HasRows)
            //    {
                    //lETS ASSUME THIS TAKES 2-3 MINUTES
            //    }
            //}

        }
    }

    private void OnDependencyChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDependency dependency = sender as SqlDependency;
        dependency.OnChange -= OnDependencyChange;
        LoadNotifications();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is the typical non-synchronous nature of data changes and app notification.  In short, changes may be happening constantly and your app will not see them happen in real-time. Furthermore, the changes may be going on whether or not your front-end app is open.  Is there a requirement to see the data as it is being changed in order to make decisions on the front-end app or do you need to review data changes made by other users.
One way in which you might achieve either is a queue of changes in the form of a table that is populated by the underlying trigger.  Then code your front-end app to periodically read from that table and mark them as read. This would allow you to de-couple the data changes from the app views and maybe see some processing performance increases.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am doing this from a sql-console job. The purpose of the job is to constantly monitor any data changes (this is the queue table - as you suggested) and send email/process it and update it/mark as read. My only concern is as I explained above what happens to the data that got added during processing. Any thoughts?